# Python PANDAS: New Column, Apply Unique Value To All Rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas, etl

Just looking for a best approach as someone who spends more time in data analysis land than programming proper (hat tip to you all).  Pretty straightforward, large ETL project but hand coding it in Python which is a first.  Fixed-width file is being read successfully into initial PANDAS df.

I am trying to add a new column with a static, end-of-month date value (2014-01-31, for example) indicating the "Data Month" for further EDW processing.  Ultimately, I am going to use datetime/timedelta functionality to pass this value as an automatically generated when I CRON it on the utility server.

My confusion seems to be about which function to utilize (apply, mapapply, etc.), if I need to reference an index value in the original df to apply a completely unrelated value to the initial df, and the most optimized, pythonic way to accomplish this.

Currently referencing: "Python for Data Analysis", PANDAS Docs.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is a small example of some fixed-width data:

```
5151022314 
5113 22204
111  20018
```

Here is some code for reading it into a PANDAS df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = 'C:\Users\Office\Desktop\example data.txt' 
widths = [2, 3, 5]
names = (['STATE_CD', 'CNTY_CD', 'ZIP_CD',])

df = pd.read_fwf(path, names=names, widths=widths, header=0)
```

This should return something like this as a df for the example date above:

```
STATE_CD,CNTY_CD,ZIP_CD
51,510,22314     
51,1  ,22204
11,3  ,20018
```

What I am trying to do is add a column "DATA_MM" like this for all rows:

```
STATE_CD,CNTY_CD,ZIP_CD, DATA_MM
51,510,22314,2014-01-31     
51,1  ,22204,2014-01-31
11,3  ,20018,2014-01-31
```

Ultimately, I am hoping to utilize something like this to generate the value that is applied automatically when this monthly job initiates:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
first = datetime.date(day=1, month=today.month, year=today.year)
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print lastMonth.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Give us a copy-paste-runnable complete minimal example, with an example of the results it should return. (Producing those is great programming practice too.)

Comment: When you say "unique", do you mean one value for each row, or one value for the whole column?

Comment: EDIT @cphlewis Thank you kindly for your prompt response. As per your request, I added a basic example. @ ASGM I mean the same value for each row for the whole column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill a column with a new value that doesn't depend on your original DataFrame, you don't need to make reference to the original indices.  You can fill the new column by simply assigning the new value to it:

```
df["DATA_MM"] = date
```

You can get the last day of the month by using `datetime` and `calendar`:

```
import datetime
import calendar

today = datetime.date.today()
y = today.year
m = today.month
eom = datetime.date(y, m, calendar.monthrange(y, m)[1])

df["DATA_MM"] = eom
```

[`monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) returns a tuple with the first and last days of the month, so `[1]` references the last day of the month.  You can also use @Alexander's method for finding the date of the last day, and assign it directly to the column instead of `apply`ing it.

Comment: Good question.  This is definitely the simple case.  I would think in your suggested case I would need to create a dictionary with all the end of month dates and iterate through them with a counter of some type if this would be automated to run monthly, correct me if I am (likely) wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm still a little confused.  Do you mean you want to add a new column every month?  If so, perhaps this would work: `df["DATA_{0}".format(date.month)] = date`?  And yes, you could iterate through a dictionary to get those dates.  I can add this to the answer, if that's indeed what you mean.

Comment: No problem. My apologies for any ambiguity. ETL processes can be idiosyncratic. I would want to create/add this column every month to the new data file.  New file grabbed/scraped and read into a new df, "data month" column is added again and this value is updated to the new EOM and applied to all new records (2014/01/31 becomes 2014/02/28), and then I have the rest of my unrelated processing for my pipeline. Does this provide adequate clarity?  I think I would ideally like to avoid a dictionary approach and be able to just grab the date via datetime library functionality. –

Comment: I see, I misunderstood about why you might want a dictionary.  I've updated it with a slightly more verbose way of determining the end of month date, but one that I hope is easier to read.  If you want to use the last month's last day, you can change `m` to `m - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your DataFrame is named df and it has a date column of Timestamps for which you would like to get end-of-month (EOM) values:

```
df['EOM date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M'))
```

You are coercing the objects to Pandas Period objects and then back to end of month timestamps, so it may not be the most efficient method.

Here is an alternative implementation with some performance stats:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', '2015-1-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['date'])

%%timeit
df.date.apply(lambda x: x.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M'))
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

%%timeit
df.date.apply(lambda x: x + pd.datetools.MonthEnd())
1 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop
```

just getting a DATETIME.DATE (per request below) for the end-of-month date from the current date can be achieve as follows:

```
pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime.now()).to_period('M').to_timestamp('M').date()
```

Comment: @ Alexander Thank you for the options.  I'll do some testing on my end.  Would it be possible to bring them back as DATE or DATETIME easily instead of TIMESTAMP?  Just a convention already used in our EDW for integration sake.

Comment: Just append .date() at the end: pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime.now()).to_period('M').to_timestamp('M').date()

Comment: Also, if you just want to assign a column a single end-of-month date value supplied via your cron job instead of calculating the EOM date given a column of different date values (as implied by your edit), then just use ASGM's suggestion for assignment:  df['EOM_date'] = pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime.now()).to_period('M').to_timestamp('M').date()

Comment: Ahh, apologies, I did not mean to imply that I would be calculating the EOM date from a column that already existed by my edit (there is no relevant date field for my full test case dataset to try that approach).  I was just pointing to a way I had been thinking of calculating the value out of whole cloth to then be applied whenever the cron job initialized via a simple SHEBANG line.  I will try this and get back to you.  Think it might do the trick.

Comment: Implied by your edit meant I had thought you wanted EOM values for a list of dates, whereas it appears you just want a single value.

Comment: That would be exactly correct.  I'll be working on this again later today.